# Transferring data from C# project to SQL server using data tables takes very long time

Tags: sql-server, database, c#-4.0

I have a C# code that generates a few data tables. I am passing this data to a stored procedure in sql server via user defined table types. This data tables are pretty big in size, say a total of 200 MB.

What I have observed is that if my data is very small in size, say 1 Mb, it gets transmitted very fast to database and the stored procedure gets executed quickly.

But when the data is large, like 200 MB, the time taken to transfer the data is very long, much longer than (time taken for 1 mb * 200) . If I see my task manager, I don't see data being continuously transmitted . I see small bursts of network activity at long intervals.

I have set command timeout to 0. The code stays in running state, does not return with an error either. In debug, the execution is at Command.ExecuteNonQuery statement

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If you're planning to do massive data loads, you probably should also check out bulk copy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: I would look for ways to change the architecture so that I am not passing such large data tables to stored procedures.